# Solve the 2 subitems into textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to solve the total count of all the large size from listview where the subitem(2) is the size and subitem(3) is the quantity and want the output into textbox.

[Here the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ72y.png)

the large size textbox only count how many "large" word in there and doest compute the quantity. i want to display the exact quantity of all the large size in textbox.

Comment: It is difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to do, would you mind giving a few more details about your situation, or a screenshot?

Comment: done editing sorry im new tnx

Comment: It would also be nice if we could see the code you have so far, that way we can more easily see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. I am sorry I couldn't test it right now.
I looped through the ListViewItems and checked if the SubItems(2) is Large. If True than increment TotalLarge by the amount in SubIems(3)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TotalLarge As Integer
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If lvi.SubItems(2).Text = "Large" Then
            TotalLarge += CInt(lvi.SubItems(3).Text)
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print(TotalLarge.ToString)
End Sub
```

There is probably a Linq method to accomplish this that is way cooler but not faster.

Comment: Thank you very much Mary you saved me now my school project is done thank you